# Upload jpg/png, convert to pdf and save with PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

Been doing a fair bit of digging this morning, and not seeing an obvious answer - is it possible to save an image to pdf format using PHP (or one of it's many libraries)?

I am fairly familiar with GD, although it doesn't seem to have a built in PDF format exporter/save function from my reading so far.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to add this to the accepted answer.  Here is an example of how to convert an image to a different format (including pdf) with the Imagick module:

```
$img = new Imagick('path/to/image.jpg');
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
$success = $img->writeImage('path/to/image.pdf');
```

OR

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($imageBytes);
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
$success = $img->writeImage('path/to/image.pdf');
```

Comment: How to add multiple images as single pdf??

Comment: @Mani check out the documentation for [writeImages](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.writeimages.php).  There is a good example at the top of user contributed notes.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 other options :

- the [pdflib extension](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.pdf.php), but the opensource edition is quite limited (I don't know if you can use image functions without a paid license)
- [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html), which is a plain-PHP lib, part of the Zend Framework.